# Stuck substring month and year in excel

Tags: excel

I would like to substring only month and year in Excel.

In example: `A1=01/15/2013`, result should be `01/2013`

How to do that in Excel?

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it:

```
=TEXT(MONTH(A1),"00")&"/"&TEXT(YEAR(A1),"00")
```

Comment: This is correct (based on the OP's question wording) in that it actually produces the substring equivalent. The other answer only displays the data in that format.

Answer (score 3):

perhaps simply

```
=TEXT(A1,"MM/YYYY")
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using excel OOTB utility. Look at the **Sample**

Refer image attached:

[image]