# Convert MSExcel date format to MM/YYYY

Tags: excel

[image]

I am working on a spreadsheet where I want to have the date in the format MM/YYYY. I have tried using cell formatting but the date doesn't show the desired format. Data validation does not give me this option. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you dates currently? I believe your dates are stored as text, and if so, some text manipulation formula would be required.

Comment: On the cell you wish to format, right click -> Format cells, click on "Custom" under Category tab, type in "mm/yyyy" below the "Type" textbox, click on OK. Where is the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17212077/stuck-substring-month-and-year-in-excel

Comment: The date is in the format dd/mm/yyyy. I have already tried to set the format through Format cells -> Custom -> mm/yyyy. However when I enter any value other than 01 for month, it defaults to 01 for the month. I therefore cannot represent any other months. As for the link from @rags, I get a circular reference warning since am using the formula in the cell that I want the date to appear. Any help with this to make it work?

Comment: @PeterKhayundi Do you have a screenshot or examples of such dates? It seems like your date format might not be dd/mm/yyyy, but mm/dd/yyyy or a mix. This can sometimes happen for wrong data extraction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a culture issue. The cell value typed into the cell is 02/01/2012. In some countries when you type in those digits it means Jan 2, 2012. In the US it means Feb 1, 2012. My laptop is US format and my friend has a computer with foreign format.

The order in which you type the date into the cell varies by country (m/d/yyyy versus d/m/yyyy). This is set by the settings in the operating system not in Excel. Excel uses the operating system settings to determine how to interpret what you type into the cell.

The format that is displayed in the cell is a separate issue. That is controlled in cell formats in Excel. You can choose whichever format you want in Excel without affecting the underlying value.

Comment: I changed the format on my machine to the region I am in and customized the date to mm/yyyy. Thank you @D_Bester for your suggestion.